# signal SIGABRT even though i'm using delete[] in c++

Tags: c++, xcode

```
Mat::Mat(int R, int C)
{
    Ar = new int[C*R];
    Co = C;
    Ro = R;
}

Mat::~Mat()
{
    delete[] Ar;
}
```

Yet i get "signal SIGABRT" on this "delete".

**EDIT:**
I use XCODE, also I tried to add a hard copy constructor. I still get this error in delete[]:

```
Mat::Mat(int R, int C)
{
    Ar = new int[C*R];
    Co = C;
    Ro = R;
}

Mat::Mat(const Mat& M): Co(M.Co), Ro(M.Ro)
{
    Ar = new int[M.Co*M.Ro];
    for (int i = 0; i<(M.Co*M.Ro); i++) {
        Ar[i] = M.Ar[i];
    }
}

Mat::~Mat()
{
    delete[] Ar;
}
```

Comment: Are you creating a `Mat` object anywhere without using your custom constructor?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can be solved by using std::vector<int> instead of int*.

Comment: Let me guess, you haven't implemented a proper copy constructor and assigment operator?

Comment: The copy constructor you have here will have you deleting a single array multiple times. This is Not Good.

Comment: A small explanation on Huw's comment: your copy constructor copies the pointer, not the actual array, so after the copy, 2 instances point to the same array and try to delete it.  Your copy constructor does nothing more than the implicitly generated copy constructor, but it should make a new array and copy each entry in that array.  (see also the rule of 3: you should also provide an assignment operator)

Answer (score 6):

This is more of psychic debugging but I am pretty much convinced, it is the root cause:
You should follow the **[Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)**.
You should provide your own ***copy constructor*** and ***copy assignment operator*** for class `Mat` which make deep copy of the pointer.

If you don't have custom versions for above mentioned functions then dynamic memory allocated to the pointer member `Ar` gets deallocated whenever a temporary copy of your class object is created and destroyed, eventually you are left with a dangling pointer member and finally `delete []` is called on it resulting an **Undefined Behavior** and a crash.

Comment: @MichaelMirkin `Ar(M.Ar)` And exactly this is the problem. It just copies the pointer, but it should allocate new storage for `Ar` and copy the actualy data. It isn't about just implementing a trivial copy constructor, the compiler can (and will) do that, too. You of course have to implement it properly. If you don't know how, then consult some introductory material on pointers and dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @MichaelMirkin: Indeed the problem is that your copy constructor makes a **Shallow copy** (*just points point member of new object being constructed to memory allocated to pointer member of object through which it is constructed*).It should make a **Deep Copy**, it should allocate memory to the pointer member of the object being constructed and then copy the contents of memory pointed by pointer member of object passed in as input argument to cctor.

Comment: Thank you my friend for your help, but still i tried it your way, by hard copy, and i get this error again.

Comment: @MichaelMirkin You also have to do it in the assignment operator, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If anywhere in your code you have something like that:

```
{
Mat A(R1,C1);//create A.Ar
MAT B(A);//now B.Ar will point to A.Ar array
}//delete will be called twice for the same array
```